# Storyboard not being displayed from the main view controller

Tags: ios, swift

I have added some logic to my main ViewController and I would like to open a controller from another storyboard if that condition is satisfied.

This is how my code in the main view controller looks like:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        let mySession = MySession.shared().get()
        if mySession?.isLoggedIn ?? true {
            let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Home", bundle: nil)
            let homeViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeVC") as! HomeViewController
            self.present(homeViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }


}
```

I have used this code on other places and it worked fine. I added a breakpoint here and this code is executing, but I am not sure why new view controller is not showing.

Comment: You shouldn't present a view controller from `viewDidLoad()`. Try it in `viewDidAppear()`.

Comment: Thanks, that solved it! Please add it as an answer, so I can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting answer, as per OP's comment...

Don't try to `present` a view controller from `viewDidLoad()`.

If you want to present a VC immediately (i.e. with the user tapping a button, for example), do so from `viewDidAppear()`.